# How to search in LDAP for group users?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

We have a group: "MyTest" in

```
OU=Domain_users,DС=my,DС=test
```

We try to find users in this group, trying:

```
(&(|(sAMAccountName=*$str*)(givenName=*$str*)(sn=*$str*)(middlename=*$str*))(memberOf=CN=MyTest))
```

and:

(memberOf=CN=MyTest,OU=Domain_users,DС=my,DС=test)

But it doesn't work. When we use filter by user name it works.

Comment: Define "it doesn't work".

Comment: I'm assuming `$str` is variable syntax in whatever language/framework you're using - what would that be? PowerShell? Perl? PHP?

Answer (score 1):

In your filter,

```
(memberOf=CN=MyTest)
```

will ensure that no results are returned. The attribute `memberOf` is a DN which is always the complete value

```
CN=MyTest,OU=Domain_users,DС=my,DС=test
```

If you are unable to find anything using the complete DN above, then just print the complete filter (to console or log) to make sure that you have a valid LDAP filter.

**EDIT**

Come to think of it, you cannot search on containment on all attributes in LDAP. Especially not `sAMAccountName` AFAIK.

Try this first:

```
(&
    (|
        (sAMAccountName=$str*)
        (givenName=$str*)
        (sn=$str*)
        (middlename=$str*)
    )
    (memberOf=CN=MyTest,OU=Domain_users,DС=my,DС=test)
)
```

And if that works, you may try to search for the attributes using a duplicate OR:

```
(|(sAMAccountName=*$str)(sAMAccountName=$str*))
```

Note the location of the wildcard.

**EDIT 2**

I took a cup of coffee and read your question again. In Active Directory, group membership is maintained on the *group* only, not on the user. So you cannot search on `memberOf` but you have to execute 2 calls: one to find the user and one to check the group membership using `(member=<user dn>)`.

Comment: Yeah, i tried full DN:
(memberOf=CN=MyTest,OU=Domain_users,DС=my,DС=test)

and it returns nothing. But in Active Directory i can see 2 users in this group

Comment: Did you print out the entire filter string? Without the variables. I would try that filter in an LDAP client, like Apache Directory Studio.

Comment: @mbreijn , yeah, i use now:

(memberOf=CN=MyTest,OU=Domain_users,DС=my,DС=test)

and it is full filter string, and returns nothing

Comment: Check my update. This has to do with server-side indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=$str*)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

Be Aware that "$str" appears to be a substitution value which may not be properly implemented in a LDAP Query.

There are some links that may help:

- https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=LDAP%20Query%20Basic%20Examples
- https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches

Comment: Hi Jim, where did you find that OID filter wisdom? On ldapwiki obviously, but before that?

Comment: As it says at:
https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN
I got it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax?redirectedfrom=MSDN

But I also did consulting with MS on several projects over the years.